# Cordova Plugin add folder to root of project

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

Making a custom cordova plugin, I need to add the sdk files to the root level of the xcode project, but it always ends up in the plugins folder of the xcode project

how do I add the folders (XIBs and MiSnap_Res) to the root of the project so they are a gold colored folder, not blue, or at least on the project level, outside the plugins folder

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
  id="com.keybank.MiSnapPlugin"
  version="0.0.1">

    <name>MiSnapPlugin</name>
    <description>MiSnapPlugin Custom Plugin Made by Derek Hannah</description>
    <author>Derek Hannah</author>
    <license>Apache 2.0 License</license>
    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.5.0" />
    </engines>
    <js-module src="www/MiSnapPlugin.js" name="MiSnapPlugin">
        <clobbers target="MiSnapPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="MiSnapPlugin">
                <param name="ios-package" value="MiSnapPlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <framework src="libstdc++.6.tbd" />
        <framework src="AudioToolbox.framework" />
        <framework src="AVFoundation.framework" />
        <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
        <framework src="CoreMedia.framework" />
        <framework src="CoreVideo.framework" />
        <framework src="MobileCoreServices.framework" />
        <framework src="QuartzCore.framework" />
        <framework src="OpenGLES.framework" />
        <framework src="Security.framework" />
        <framework src="ImageIO.framework" />
        <framework src="Foundation.framework" />
        <framework src="Foundation.framework" />
        <framework src="UIKit.framework" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/libMiSnap.a" framework="true" />

        <resource-file src="src/ios/MiSnap_Res"/>

        <source-file src="src/ios/XIBs" target-dir="../.."/>

        <header-file src="src/ios/include/MiSnap.h" />
        <header-file src="src/ios/MiSnapPlugin.h" />

        <source-file src="src/ios/MiSnapPlugin.m" />
    </platform>


    <!--<platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="HelloWorldPlugin"> 
                <param name="android-package" value="mobi.monaca.HelloWorldPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/mobi/monaca/HelloWorldPlugin.java" target-dir="src/mobi/monaca" />        
    </platform>-->

</plugin>
```